# A sum of two symmetrical numbers resulting in a symmetrical number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, multivariable-calculus

symmetrical numbers are like 12021, or 818, or 2250522, or 11..etc whereas 255 is not, find the largest possible symmetrical number that you can add 2017 to, and still result in a symmetrical number.

is there a generalized formula for this? I already know the answer for the upper question, but i'll leave it as a challenge. (can you use a function?)

Comment: as far as I know a formula doesnt exist, but it is easy to compute.

Comment: How then, is it usually computed with larger numbers?

Comment: how large?${}{}{}{}$